# Writing an MSBuild for a solution with many C# projects

Tags: msbuild

I am very new to MSBuild. I am attempting two different paths toward a solution. Test is giving me errors and Compile is working but I'm not even sure if it does anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
<AssemblyName>MSBuildSample</AssemblyName>
<OutputPath>Output\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
<Reference Include="**\*.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
 <ProjectsToBuild Include="**\*proj" Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Test">
<MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)"      Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" />
<Csc Sources="@(Compile)"  References="@(Reference)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).exe" />
<Message Text="The output file is done"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="Clean">
<MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Clean"
        Properties="Configuration= $(Configuration)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
<MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" ContinueOnError="false" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
  <Output ItemName="BuildOutput" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
</MSBuild>
</Target>

</Project>
```

Am I headed down the right path at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply pass a solution file as project to the `MSBuild` task:

```
<MSBuild Projects="MySolution.sln"  />
```

OR

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(PathToSolutionFile)"  />
```

If this is not a case for you please let me know

**EDIT:** Answer to comments

From MSDN, [MSBuild Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx):

> This task can process not only project files but also solution files.

`MSBuild` does NOT create solution files. Considering you have a solution file which includes both projects you've mentioned - you can just specify single solution file and MSBuild pickup all projects which are included.

Perhaps you need this one:
[How to: Create Solutions and Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is this cheating? Does Visual Studio create the solution file?

If not, then I have:

    <ItemGroup>
     <Compile Include="*.sln" />
     </ItemGroup>

     <Target Name="Test">
     <MSBuild Projects="@(Compile)"  />
     </Target>

This works but I'm not sure what it does. What do I do now?

Comment: I appreciate the help. Sorry if these are silly questions, I am new to MSBuild and Stackoverflow in general. What must be done besides the build? What about cleaning, or deployment?

Comment: If you are Import standard Microsoft Targets it will provide you Cleaning, deployment more complex thing, basically take a look at COPY task, idea is to copy from $(OutDir) to your custom $(DeploymentDir)

Comment: It turns out this is Silverlight. Do you know how that differs?

Comment: @Shazam : Have not experience with Silverlight but I believe there is the same idea of single solution with multiple projects?